# rj package compilation failure

Tags: macos, r, compilation, java-native-interface, statet

Thanks a lot for taking a look. There's a previous post on here with the same error message "cannot compile a simple JNI program" and the solution was to update to R 1.15. But I've already had everything in the newest version. Although it says "see config.log for details", it doesn't give a location, and "find / -name config.log" at the terminal returns nothing.

It's be an exhausting and frustrating process trying to get this to work. Any help will be much appreciated.

R version 2.15.1, 64-bit (I used Homebrew install, but it shouldn't be the problem)

Eclipse 4.2 Cocoa, 64-bit (tried 3.7 as well, didn't work either)

OSX 10.7.5

Here's the error message:

```
install.packages(c("rj"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-1.1")
Installing package(s) into '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://download.walware.de/rj-1.1/src/contrib/rj_1.1.0-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-tar' length 314501 bytes (307 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 307 Kb

* installing *source* package 'rj' ...
checking R config... found
    R_HOME   : /usr/local/Cellar/r/2.15.1/R.framework/Resources
checking for gcc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking Java support in R... ok
    JAVA_HOME: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    JAVA     : /usr/bin/java
    JAVAC    : /usr/bin/javac
    JAVAH    : /usr/bin/javah
    JAVA_CPPFLAGS: -I/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/include
    JAVA_LIBS: -framework JavaVM
    JAR      : /usr/bin/jar

configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
=== configuring in jri (/private/var/folders/7p/q7qb1n2d277c9tqt65s5wy_c0000gn/T/RtmpVlP2YK/R.INSTALL2c9175fac4e/rj/jri)
configure: running /bin/sh ./configure --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/usr/local'  --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking for gcc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
yes
checking whether Java interpreter works... checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... configure: error: Cannot compile a simple JNI program. See config.log for details.
configure: error: ./configure failed for jri
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rj'
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/rj'
* restoring previous '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/rj'

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/private/var/folders/7p/q7qb1n2d277c9tqt65s5wy_c0000gn/T/RtmpNM4Pyx/downloaded_packages'
Warning message:
In install.packages(c("rj"), repos = "http://download.walware.de/rj-1.1") :
  installation of package 'rj' had non-zero exit status
```

Here is the session info.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tcltk_2.15.1 tools_2.15.1
```

Comment: For those able to help (that won't be me) it might be useful for you to explain why what you've attempted here doesn't seem to match the [installation instructions](http://www.walware.de/?page=/it/rj/index.mframe).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The instruction says install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-1.1"). I'm just installing the first package and not both at the same time. If it helps anyone to know: using the exact command on my machine produces the same error for the other package as well.

Comment: That was all I meant (I wasn't sure whether installing both made a difference or not).

Comment: Ah I was hoping you spotted something that might be the cause of the error. Thanks for bringing it up nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and below Solution worked for me. Please follow the steps

1.) You need to run this command on the terminal - R CMD javareconf
2.) After that check the compatibility of StatET with rJ package which is in below order.

For RJ 2.0 (StatET 3.4 - 3.5):
install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-2.0")

For RJ 1.1 (StatET 3.0 - 3.3):
install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-1.1")

For RJ 1.0 (StatET 2.0):
install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-1.0")

For RJ 0.5 (StatET 0.10):
install.packages("rj", repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-0.5")

3.) Once you know your compatible version in accordance with StatET then run the package installation command.
 for example. I am using a StatET 3.5 thus for me RJ 2.0 will work and not others .

So command would be 
{install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-2.0")}

4.) Once your installation is done then do check the environmental variable are set correctly in case you are using any IDE ( Like Eclipse ). Library paths should be set in Eclipse or any other IDE.

Follow this link in case of any issues - http://www.walware.de/?page=/it/statet/installation.html

Comment: Hi Ravi, welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your answer. As links can change and become invalid over time, can you please edit your answer to provide the pertinent troubleshooting information here, rather than relying on the link entirely? You can provide the link for context still, but it is better for your answer to also contain the necessary information.

Comment: Hi @TimMalone - Edited ( Thanks for your inputs )

Comment: You're welcome. One more thing - you might find it helpful to put the commands within code formatting. Use backticks (`) or put them on a new paragraph, indented by 4 spaces.

Comment: Hi @TimMalone Let me know if the answer is helpful to others.